# html how can write and create function into jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
if (temp == 'Gps') {
    $('#tabs-1').html('<fieldset class="fieldstyle"><legend>Label</legend><input type="text" id="titlebox-' + id + '" value="' + temp + '"/></fieldset><br><p><label>Add to PunchList</label><input type="checkbox" id="punchlist" class="require"/></p><p><label>Mandatory Field</label><input type="checkbox" id="mfield" class="require"/></p><p><label>Include in PDF Export?</label><input type="checkbox" id="pdf" class="require"/></p><br> <fieldset class="fieldstyle"><legend>Field Description</legend><textarea id="instructmsg" value="' + inst + '"></textarea></fieldset> ');
}

else if (temp == 'Photo') {
    $('#tabs-1').html('<fieldset class="fieldstyle"><legend>Label</legend><input type="text" id="titlebox-' + id + '" value="' + temp + '"/></fieldset><br><p><label>Add to PunchList</label><input type="checkbox" id="punchlist" class="require"/></p><p><label>Mandatory Field</label><input type="checkbox" id="mfield" class="require"/></p><p><label>Include in PDF Export?</label><input type="checkbox" id="pdf" class="require"/></p><br> <fieldset class="fieldstyle"><legend>Field Description</legend><textarea id="instructmsg" value="' + inst + '"></textarea></fieldset> ');
}
```

The html code above is repeated. How can I write a function for this using jquery and how can I call that function? How can it be loaded? How do I write all this into a single js page?

Comment: Why are you using a conditional and then performing the same function call in each branch?

Comment: You can create a function using `function name(){ ... }`, then use: `name()` to call that function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `||`(*Logical OR*) operator:

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, `||` returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns false.

```
function simple() { // define a function
   // ...
   if (temp == 'Gps' || temp == 'Photo') {
      $('#tabs-1').html('...')
   }
}

simple() // call the function
```

Comment: I can't tell if OP wants a regular JavaScript function or an actual jQuery function.

Comment: @saml Yes, the question is too basic.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally want a jQuery function to do this, let's say you call it `myFunction`, you can do it like this:

```
$.fn.myFunction(id, temp, inst) {
    return this.html('<fieldset class="fieldstyle"><legend>Label</legend><input type="text" id="titlebox-'+id+'" value="'+temp+'"/></fieldset><br><p><label>Add to PunchList</label><input type="checkbox" id="punchlist" class="require"/></p><p><label>Mandatory Field</label><input type="checkbox" id="mfield" class="require"/></p><p><label>Include in PDF Export?</label><input type="checkbox" id="pdf" class="require"/></p><br> <fieldset class="fieldstyle"><legend>Field Description</legend><textarea id="instructmsg" value="'+inst+'"></textarea></fieldset> ');
}
```

But your conditional is bad. You shouldn't use multiple branches to do the same thing.  Using the function created above,

```
if (temp === 'Gps' || temp === 'Photo') {
    $('#tabs-1').myFunction(id, temp, inst);
}
```